# Using a SQL query to update multiple rows by stepping through a list/table of values

Tags: sql, sql-server

So currently I use a simple SQL query to update these sale records with a cancellation date when the date is outside the range that is restricted in the frontend of the database program:

```
declare @IDnumber varchar(50) = 'XX00999999'
declare @canceldate datetime = cast('2022-11-01 14:15' as datetime)

begin transaction

update [dbo].[XSaleHeader]
SET CANCELLEDDATE = @canceldate, CANCELLEDUSERID = 999, CANCELLEDUSERISSYSUSER = 1
where XIDNUMBER = @IDnumber

rollback transaction
--commit transaction
```

I am routinely getting a list of these at each month's end and would like to make this process quicker by making the query more suitable, making changes to the front end would be more costly.

What I want to do is feed the stored procedure a list I can copy from excel which will simply be:

| IDNUMBERS | canceldate |
| --- | --- |
| XX0999998 | 10/11/2022 |
| XX0999999 | 10/11/2022 |

For each pair of values in the table I need it to set the two values and the CANCELLEDUSERID and CANCELLEDUSERISSYSUSER values for audit fields.

I expect I'll need to cast the date and have it add a generic time like 09:00 to it for each value?
But beyond that I've looked through several posts and can see some items that show using in line lists in brackets but not a table.

I'm thinking that maybe I may just need to pop the IDs through a textjoin to get a comma list, and the dates through something like
`=TEXTJOIN(" ",,TEXT(I155,"yyyy-mm-dd"),"09:00")` and then another textjoin to pop the date strings for both columns then `=TEXTJOIN("','",,I155:I387)` to get all the date strings into a list I can just then paste. *(I'm just trying to put as much I can into something I can save and reuse to save future time)*.

But I can't see any responses that don't involve writing a case statement for a finite number of IDs/dates, rather than something that will step through the list of IDs and assign each one a date (there will always be the same number of IDs and dates).

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The above code is product specific.)

Comment: I'm using MS SQL 2014

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a temp table, table variable or custom table type.

I'll show the temp table approach, since it's not in a stored procedure there is no need for a custom table type.

You'll still need to construct the insert values in Excel or any other editor.
If it's a CSV file you could also use `BULK Insert` or `OPENROWSET` to insert into the temp table.

```
-- Create a temp table to hold the excel data
CREATE TABLE #excelRecords(IdNumber VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, CancelDate DATETIME)

-- Insert all the excel rows into the temp table
INSERT INTO #excelRecords(IdNumber, CancelDate)
VALUES 
-- Add your values
('123', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
, ('456', 'yyyy-MM-dd')
-- Construct this in excel: , ( 'IdNumber', 'CancelDate')

-- Update the destination
update sh
    SET CANCELLEDDATE = er.CancelDate,
        CANCELLEDUSERID = 999, 
        CANCELLEDUSERISSYSUSER = 1
FROM  [dbo].[XSaleHeader] sh
-- Use an inner join to filter the records to update
INNER JOIN  #excelRecords er on er.IdNumber = sh.XIDNUMBER
```